# Trouble retrieving list of facebook friends from json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using FBSDK in my Swift iOS application and currently I am trying to retrieve the **list of friends who also use my app.** I have two-three people who should show up but whenever I search the graphrequest result for friends it returns nil..

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",     parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection,     result:AnyObject!, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                //get Facebook ID
                let faceBookID: NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as NSString
                //get username
                let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as NSString
                //get facebook friends who use app
                let friendlist: AnyObject = result.valueForKey("friends") as AnyObject

            }
```

I have the "email", "user_friends", and "public_profile" permissions which should be enough to retrieve this information. Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong?? this is doing my head in as my friend doing an android version has successfully got his working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was that I never Actually requested for the list of friends in my facebook graph request...

after replacing `FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",     parameters: nil)`

with `FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=id,name,friends",     parameters: nil)`

I was able to retrieve the list of friends because the response actually contained information for this. A very trivial mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

> In v2.0 of the Graph API, you must request the user_friends permission
>   from each user. user_friends is no longer included by default in every
>   login. Each user must grant the user_friends permission in order to
>   appear in the response to /me/friends.

see here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/

Comment: thanks for the response! The Graph API will let you request the list of _friends who also use your app_ and have granted the app the same basic permission "user_friends". My problem was I never actually requested this list of friends in the graph path value.